# Historical information about dustmen in Edwardian England

Tags: england

I'm helping a middle schooler who was assigned Shaw's *Pygmalion*. I found a nice write-up about flower girls but now I need something about dustmen. For example, why does Alfred Doolittle, dustman, wear leather? I'm not looking for that question to be answered here -- this is just an example of the sort of information that should be included in the write-up I seek.

[This](http://www.guthrietheater.org/sites/default/files/pygmalion.pdf) is the closest I've gotten so far, but that text is confusing.

The other study guides I've tried have character analysis of Doolittle. I'm looking for straight historical information about the trade of dustman.

Comment: I'm not sure 19th-century is the right tag.  20th-century would be misleading.  I wanted "Edwardian" but it didn't exist.

Comment: How is the text confusing?  Why doesn't "In the process of their work they pushed the sieve from them and drew it back again with apparent
violence, striking it against the outer leathern apron with such force that it produced each time a hollow sound, like a blow on the tenor drum." answer the question?  (if I'm striking myself with enough force to generate a drumbeat, I want a couple of layers of stalwart padding between sieve & me.)

Comment: You might want to consult [this](http://player.bfi.org.uk/film/watch-dustmen-1959/), or search google for "London Dustmen 1900...1910 -image" - there seem to be quite a few sources.